# Apply discount in WooCommerce check out based on selected field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am planning on using Woocommerce to register people for a small conference. We have a list of about 300 companies that should get a ticket discount.

Is there a way to add a field to the check out form that will allow the user to select which company they work for and have a discount applied to their ticket purchase?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use the [Checkout Field Editor](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/checkout-field-editor/) plugin to add custom fields to your checkout form.

> The Checkout Field Editor provides an interface to add, edit and remove fields shown on your WooCommerce checkout page.

It might take a bit of custom implementation to get the functionality that you want, but it seems like this might do it.